# Snowflake IP whitelist

Tags: ip, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, whitelist

Hi I have a list of IP's whitelisted in snowflake and I am able to log on to Snowflake thru my companies network however I cannot log on from home. When I look at the IP whitelist I do not see my laptops IP on the list nor do I see the IP or the company's router.  Clearly I am missing something but what is it ? The ip white list in SF is active.

Comment: Have you checked the [network policy at both user/account level](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/network-policies.html#identifying-a-network-policy-activated-at-the-account-or-user-level)?

Comment: Not an anwser as I've never used snowflake data services but maybe they're filtering by mac (hardware) address  in addition to IP, since this value doesn't change on a device and IPs are typically dynamic

Comment: It sounds like the security policy of not allow random IP's to connect is working. VPN into you office whitelist network, and then you should be good. Unless you are VPN'ed but the IP address block of the VPN in not in the whitelist, at which point the those will need to be added also.

Answer (score 1):

If you log on from home and are not using a VPN into your company network, then your IP will be assigned by your home router/ISP. This IP will obviously not be whitelisted so you therefore won’t be able to connect to Snowflake